# Botones flotantes no funcionan de manera esperada

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

Quiero colocar un botón flotante de opciones que al realizar el hover se desplieguen 4 botones más para la ventana de caja: las opciones serían abrir caja, cerrar caja, imprimir y entrada / salida.

Hasta ahora lo logre con el siguiente código:

[ejemplo](https://codepen.io/waynelkh/pen/rapjbJ)

Pero el caso es que se me mezcla con el botón que abre el sidebar que tengo escondido a la izquierda dado que es de tipo btn, y al querer ir a un determinado botón se esconden los tres:

Asi es como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veran el toggle del menu que estaba arriba a la izquierda se cambia y aparece solo al hacer hover..no se que estoy haciendo mal.
Añadop el codigo JQUERY al salir del contenedor para que se escondan los 3 botones flotantes, lom publico porque no puedo acceder al segundo y tercero:

Vuelvo a colocar todo el codigo junto, y el problema es que al salir del boton flotante de clase .botonF1, los demas botones se desaparecen y no se puede hacer click sobre ellos.

```js
     
$('.botonF1').hover(function(){

  $('.btn2').addClass('animacionVer');
 
});
$('.contenedor').mouseleave(function(){
  $('.btn2').removeClass('animacionVer');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="views/modules/caja/caja.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
*{
  margin:0;
}
header{
  height:170px;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:Sans-serif;
  background:#009688;
  padding-top:30px;
  padding-left:50px;
}
.contenedor{
  width:90px;
  height:240px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;
  bottom:0px;
}
.botonF1{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:100%;
  background:#F44336;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  position:fixed;
  margin-right:26px;
  margin-bottom:16px;
  border:none;
  outline:none;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:36px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  transition:.3s;  
}
span{
  transition:.5s;  
}
.botonF1:hover span{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
}
.botonF1:active{
  transform:scale(1.1);
}
.btn2{
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  border-radius:100%;
  border:none;
  color:#FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
  font-size:20px;
  outline:none;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin-right:26px;
  transform:scale(0);
}
.botonF2{
  background:#2196F3;
  margin-bottom:110px;
  transition:0.5s;
}
.botonF3{
  background:#673AB7;
  margin-bottom:180px;
  transition:0.7s;
}
.botonF4{
  background:#009688;
  margin-bottom:250px;
  transition:0.9s;
}
.botonF5{
  background:#FF5722;
  margin-bottom:320px;
  transition:0.99s;
}
.animacionVer{
  transform:scale(1);
}

</style>
<form method="POST" action="views/modules/caja/reportecaja.php">
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card" style="width: 1280px;">
                <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;height: 10px;">DATOS DE SESION</h5>  
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>CAJERO.:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?>"/>
                            <label><?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo $_SESSION['username'];}?></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>HORA INICIO:<?php if (isset($_SESSION['inicio'])){echo $_SESSION['inicio'];}?></label>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>HORA FIN:<?php  date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires");$horaactual=date("H:i:s"); echo $horaactual;?></label>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label> Efectivo:</label>
                            <label id="subtotal"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Cambio:</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cambio" placeholder="QUEDA EN CAJA" id="cambio"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label>Total</label>
                            <label id="total"></label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div id="contenedor" class="contenedor">
<button class="botonF1" id="opciones" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="OPCIONES" style="color: black;">
  <span><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i></span>
</button>
<button class="btn2 botonF2" id="abrircaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ABRIR CAJA" style="color: black;">
  <span><i class="fas fa-lock-open"></i></span>
</button>
<button class="btn2 botonF3" id="cerrarcaja" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="CERRAR CAJA" style="color: black;">
  <span><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
</button>
<button class="btn2 botonF4" id="es" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="ENTRADA/SALIDA" style="color: black;">
  <span><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i></span>
</button>
<button class="btn2 botonF5" id="imprimir" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="left" data-content="IMPRIMIR" style="color: black;">
  <span><i class="fas fa-print"></i></span>
</button>
 </div>




<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 1280px;">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                        

                                                       
                            <h3 class="panel-title" style="text-align: center;">LISTADO DE MOVIMIENTOS DEL TURNO</h3>  
                       </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">                  
<table id="resumen" class="table table-hover">

<title>Comprobantes</title>
<thead class="thead-dark">

</thead><tfoot><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tfoot>

<tbody>

</tbody>
</table></div>
  </div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Y si nombras a tu código flotante como `.btn2`, por ejemplo? Esa sería la solución más simple.

Comment: Se soluciono el problema el boton toggle, solo que ahora al pasar el primer boton se desaparecen los tres, es decir no se puede hacer click en el segundo o tercero

Comment: Yo hice el mio propio quiza te sirva https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/260392/dise%C3%B1o-de-botones-flotantes-con-css#answer-260632

Comment: Se soluciono colocando el contenedor al final de la pagina y aumentando su heigth a los pixeles suficientes para que entren todos los botones en el mismo